# IntersectWith.None VB.NET AutoCAD

Tags: vb.net, autocad

I have a problem with the function IntersectWith

I have used this function with VBA and it has a option `Intersect.None`

But when I call the function from VB.NET this option does not exist.
I try to use the available options but all detect an incorrect intersection

```
yourCADObjectII.IntersectWith(myText, Intersect.ExtendBoth, points, New IntPtr(0), New IntPtr(0)) 

yourCADObjectII.IntersectWith(myText, Intersect.OnBothOperands, points, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)

yourCADObjectII.IntersectWith(myText, Intersect.ExtendArgument, points, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)

yourCADObjectII.IntersectWith(myText, Intersect.ExtendThis, points, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
```

I don't know how to use `IntersectWith` in VB.NET as I used in VBA with the `Intersect.None` option.

I tried to detect a text string vs. a closed polyline, the text is inside of a polyline, I want to detect if the text intersects with the `LWPolyline`.

The text has different rotations and the polyline has different geometry.

Answer (score 0):

As far as know, the COM/ActiveX `IntersectWith` method does not have any `Intersect.None` option. It has a `acExtendNone` option whose .NET equivalent is `Intersect.OnBothOperands`.

```
COM                  .NET

acExtendNone         Intersect.OnBothOperands  Does not extend either object.

acExtendThisEntity   Intersect.ExtendThis      Extends the base object.

acExtendOtherEntity  Intersect.ExtendArgument  Extends the object passed as an argument.

acExtendBoth         Intersect.ExtendBoth      Extends both objects.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are implementing IntersectWith correctly and your problem is not with what you mentioned. From memory, when you try to use intersectwith for DBText with any other object, it doesn't actually calculate the intersection with the text itself but rather with its bounding box. And that bounding box doesn't always fit the text exactly. It sometimes is bigger than the text (depending on rotation). Or sometimes it is smaller than the text especially when using letters like (y, j, q,g, etc...)

So your best bet is to try and find the bounding box that fits your rotated text by finding the bounding box that fits the same text with no rotation then rotate that box (using a closed polyline to capture all 4 corners)
Now your problem becomes intersection of two polylines instead of text and polyline. And then you can use intersectWith to get intersection points

Comment: Thanks, I will work around your idea to find a solution to my program.